# exercise in Tao analysis I book

Tags: foundations

I am supposed to prove that if a is a positive natural number then there exists exactly one number b, such that the increment of b is equal to a.

My idea was to induct from the base case a = 1, but I am I can't proceed this way because I haven't yet established that 1 is the smallest positive number (I don't even have the concept of 'greater than' defined.) I have the fact that 0 is not a successor of any natural number, so I tried to use that but without success.

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Without knowing what you are allowed to assume (I do not have this book), I would try a proof by contradiction using the well ordering principle of the natural numbers "Every subset of the natural numbers has a least element," though that might be hard without inequalities. What are you allowed to assume?

Comment: Peano's axioms, I don't have well-ordering, but I do have principle of induction.

Answer (score 4):

You probably need an axiom equivalent to $a=b$ iff $S(a)=S(b)$, which would be axiom 8 of the [Peano axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms). In that case you should be able to find at least one predecessor using the definition of a natural number, and then it is easy to see that it is unique because all predecessors must be equal.

Comment: I do have that axiom available, but I still don't get how to use it, since it doesn't affirm an existence of anything.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by definition of natural number?

Comment: @Adam: The natural numbers are defined as precisely those things which are either $0$ or a successor of another natural number. As I said, you need this first to get at least one predecessor, and then use the injectivity of $S$ to show that all predecessors are equal.

Comment: I have: 0 is a natural number and if b is a natural number than S(b) is also a natural number. Can I use these two facts to prove this?

Comment: @Adam: No the fact you last stated isn't actually needed. $0$ satisfies the "definition" I gave for a natural number, and for any natural number that satisfies that, its successor also does. So induction proves the definition for all natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

We have :

> to prove that if $a$ is a positive natural number then there exists exactly one number $b$, such that the increment of $b$ is equal to $a$.

Assuming that "the increment of $x$" is the *successor* of $x$, i.e. $S(x)$, we have in symbols :

> $\forall a (a \ne 0 \rightarrow \exists ! b (S(b)=a))$.

We prove it using *first-order* [Peano's axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms), i.e. the theory $\mathsf {PA}$, and in particular I will follow Stephen Cole Kleene, [Introduction to Metamathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0923891579) (1952), page 181-on.

---

*Uniqueness* follows from the axiom :

> $∀x,y ( S(x) = S(y) \rightarrow x = y)$.

Assume that :

$\exists b_1 \exists b_2 (S(b_1)=a \land S(b_2)=a)$.

Then, by property of *equality*, $S(b_1)=S(b_2)$; thus, form the above axioms, we conclude with $b_1=b_2$.

---

For the *existence* of $b$, where $b$ is the *successor* of $a$, we have to prove that :

> $\forall a (a \ne 0 \rightarrow \exists b (S(b)=a))$.

The proof is by Induction on $a$, where the induction formula is : $\mathcal A(a) := (a \ne 0 \rightarrow \exists b (S(b)=a))$.

*Basis* : $\mathcal A(0)$. We need the *tautology* : $A \rightarrow (\lnot A \rightarrow B)$, with $A := 0 = 0$ and $B := \exists b (S(b)=0)$.

Using the logical theorem : $\vdash 0 = 0$ [by substitution in the *identity axiom* : $\vdash x = x$], by *modus ponens* we derive :

> $0 \ne 0 \rightarrow \exists b (S(b)=0)$ --- $\mathcal A(0)$

*Induction step* : $\mathcal A(S(a))$. Again from identity axiom we have $S(a)=S(a)$; thus, by $\exists$-intro :

$\exists b (S(b)=S(a))$.

Having proved it, from the *logical axiom* : $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$, by *modus ponens* we derive :

> $S(a) \ne 0 \rightarrow \exists b (S(b)=S(a))$ --- $\mathcal A(S(a))$ .

We have proved : $\vdash \mathcal A(0)$ and $\vdash \mathcal A(S(a))$; but form the last one, by properties of *derivability*, we have : $\mathcal A(a) \vdash \mathcal A(S(a))$.

Thus, applying *Induction schema* : if $\Gamma \vdash \mathcal A(0)$ and $\Gamma, \mathcal A(x) \vdash \mathcal A(S(x))$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \mathcal A(x)$, with $\Gamma = \emptyset$, we conclude with : $\forall a \mathcal A(a)$, i.e.

> > $\forall a(a \ne 0 \rightarrow \exists b (S(b)=a))$.

---

*Added*

Please, consider [Robinson arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic), or $\mathsf {Q}$, which is a finitely axiomatized fragment of Peano arithmetic, first set out by R.M.Robinson (1950) : $\mathsf {Q}$ is essentially $\mathsf {PA}$ without the axiom schema of induction.

In $\mathsf {Q}$ we have the axiom :

> $\forall x(x = 0 \lor \exists y(Sy = x))$

which is exactly :

> > $\forall x(x \ne 0 \rightarrow \exists y(Sy = x))$.

Comment: I dont't think your rendition of the proposition into logical symbols is correct, because in the case a=0 b is not unique.

Comment: @Adam - I fear that my answer is confusing, because I "swapped" the logical order, which is : first = existence, second = uniqueness. But the *existence* part is $a≠0→∃b(S(b)=a)$. Thus, for $a=0$, the theorem simply does not apply.

Comment: @Adam - but this is consistent with your statement : "to prove that if $a$ is a positive natural number then there exists exactly one number $b$, such that...". Clearly, for *natural numbers*, $a$ positive means $a \ne 0$.

Comment: @Adam - the same proof (without tedious details) is in Carl Mummert's answer to your following [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844887/proof-by-induction-that-every-non-zero-natural-number-has-a-predecessor)