# What is the definition of the "order" of well order property in Peano Axioms?

Tags: natural-numbers, peano-axioms, well-orders

For Peano Axiom, mathematical induction is equivalent to well order property.

But in well order property, what is the definition of "order"?

In detail, if we define the "order" $b\le c$ as:

$b = c$ or exist a finite (may be zero) number of natural numbers $a_1,... ,a_n$​​ such that: $(s(b)=a_1)\ \wedge\ (s(a_1)=a_2)\ \wedge \ ...\ \wedge\ (s(a_n)=c)$​

($s(i)=j$ means that, natural number $j$ is the successor of $i$.)

And the corollary:

$\forall i\in \mathbb N \setminus \{0\},\ \exists j\in \mathbb N$​ such that $s(j)=i$​​​​​​

will be trivial, since $\mathbb N$ has minimum element $0$ and $\forall i\in \mathbb N$, $i\geq 0$ means that $i=0$ or $s(0)=a_1 ... s(a_n)=i$, so we can prove that exist $a_n$ such that $s(a_n)=i$.

It seems so wired. Because if we don't use well order property, we need to prove the corollary using induction([proof by induction that every non-zero natural number has a predecessor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844887/proof-by-induction-that-every-non-zero-natural-number-has-a-predecessor)), and the proof steps for me is not trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In second order logic you can express the relation $m\le n$ by the formula
$$\forall U(Um\land(\forall t (Ut\rightarrow U(St)))\rightarrow Un)$$
where $S$ stands for successor, U is a variable quantifying over all subsets of the domain of discourse, and lowercase variables quantify over objects in the domain.

In first order logic, AFAIK there is no formula $\Psi(x,y)$ with free variables $x,y$ such that $\Psi(x,y)\iff x\le y$.  However, if you introduce a binary relation symbol $\le$ into the language you can axiomatize it as follows

- $\forall x (x\le x)$
- $\forall x\forall y (x\le y \land y\le x\rightarrow x=y)$
- $\forall x\forall y\forall z (x\le y \land y \le z \rightarrow x\le z)$
- $\forall x\forall y(x\le y \lor y \le x)$
- $\forall x (0\le x)$
- $\forall x\forall y(x\le y\land x\ne y\leftrightarrow Sx\le y)$

Comment: Get it, and I want to ask another question:

Can I use your first (Second order logic) definition of "order" :
$$
∀U(Um∧(∀t(Ut→U(St)))→Un)\tag{1}
$$
to prove the equivalence among first induction, well-ordering property, and Strong induction?

(Because the true question I want to ask is "use well-ordering property to prove induction", so I need a definition of "order" without recursively being defined. And sorry for not mention this question at first.)

Comment: Since in the first answer to my question, for proving the equivalence between well-ordering property and Strong induction we need the "order" to satisfy:
$$
\forall x\forall y(x\le y\ \vee\ y\le x)\tag{2}
$$
for proving:
$$
a\not < b\rightarrow a\ge b
$$
(So we can " phrase the well-ordering property as $\exists y(y\in A)→∃y(y∈A∧∀z(z<y→z∉A))$​​​")

Comment: And for proving the equivalence between first induction and Strong induction, "order" needs to satisfy:
$$
\forall x\ (0\leq x)\tag{3}
$$
for proving:
$$
0\in \{y∣∀z(z<y→z∈B)\}
$$
(So we can use $0∈C∧∀y(y∈C→S(y)∈C)→∀y(y∈C)$​ to prove $∀y(y∈C→S(y)∈C)→∀y(y∈C)$​)

Comment: and we need:
$$
\forall x\forall y(x\le y\ \wedge\ y\ne x\rightarrow S(x)\le y)\tag{4}
$$
for proving:
$$
\forall y(\forall z(z<y\rightarrow z\in B)\ \wedge\ y\in B\rightarrow \forall z(z<S(y)\rightarrow z\in B))
$$
And is the order $(1)$​ satisfy $(2),\ (3)$ and $(4)$​ in any condition?

(And for your second definition of "order", I think we only need to add $\forall y\ (y< S(y))$​, and the equivalence of three can be proved.)

Comment: Thx, and I finally know I can use definition $(1)$​ to prove $(2)$​ $(3)$​ $(4)$​, when I combine $(1)$​ with well-ordering property and other Peano Axioms. $(2)$​ is because $\forall x\forall y(\{x,y\}\subseteq\mathbb N)$​ and well-ordering property, $(3)$​ is because 0 is not a successor, and $(4)$​ is because $\forall x\forall y(x\neq y\rightarrow S(x)\neq S(y))$​ and the definition of $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of $\le$ does not work well because it seems to be an *infinitary* conjunction. The Peano *axioms* are supposed to be interpreted in a logic that is second (or higher) order but still *finitary* -- every formula is finite string of symbols.

The usual definition of $\le$ in this setting is
$$ x \le y \iff \exists z(x+z=y) $$
after we have defined addition recursively, of course.

We can then phrase the well-ordering property as
$$ \tag1 \exists y(y\in A) \to \exists y(y\in A \land \forall z(z< y\to z\notin A)) $$
which is logically equivalent to a second-order formulation of *long* induction:
$$ \tag2 \forall y(\forall z(z<y \to z\in B) \to y\in B) \to \forall y(y\in B) $$
(Namely, let $A$ be the complement of $B$ (or vice versa) and contrapose the outermost $\to$).

It then takes a bit of footwork to prove (2) from the usual second-order *mathematical* induction axiom
$$ \tag3 0\in C \land \forall y(y\in C\to S(y)\in C) \to \forall y(y\in C) $$
and the recursive definition of addition. Basically, to get (2) you would apply (3) with $C=\{y\mid \forall z(z<y\to z\in B)\}$.

Comment: Why I came up with this question is that I want to use well-ordering property to prove inductions.

But in your proof, if I want to prove inductions, I will have 2 problems:

Comment: 1. The order "$\le$​" is recursively defined. But I want to prove inductions, which is the bedrock of the correctness of recursive method. So I can't define anything recursively if I want to get a linear order.

Comment: 2. In the partial order set $(\mathbb N,\le)$​​​, there can be no any partial order relation between two element.  $a\not <b$​​​ is equal to $((a,b)\not\in\le) \vee (a\ge b)$​​​, so  well-ordering property is not equivalent to your format above:

Comment: in detail:
   $$
   \forall A((A\subseteq \mathbb N\ \wedge\ A\neq \emptyset)\rightarrow \exists y(y\in A\ \wedge\ \forall z(z\in A\rightarrow z\ge y)))
   $$

   $$
   z\in A\rightarrow z\ge y
   $$

   is equivalent to:
   $$
   (z<y\ \vee\ (z,y)\not\in\le)\rightarrow z\in A^c
   $$
   but not equivalent to:
   $$
   z<y\rightarrow z\in A^c
   $$